# Format '%c' expects argument of type 'char'

Tags: c++

The error I receive is:

```
program3.cpp:13:21: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ [-Wformat=]
```

I'm probably lacking a very fundamental part of knowledge about the C++ language and I apologise for asking this novice question (once again). Also I would appreciate it if you could give feedback or point out other flaws in my code.
What is wrong in my C++ code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int harga=20000;
    int diskon;
    char pelanggan;
    string jenisp;
    printf("Apakah Pelanggan : [Y/N]");
    scanf("%c",&pelanggan);
    if(pelanggan=='Y'){
        printf("Apa Jenis Pelanggan [Emas,Perak,Perunggu]:");
        scanf("%c",&jenisp);
        if(jenisp=="Emas"){
            diskon=harga-(0.5*harga);
            printf("Harga untuk pelanggan kartu Emas adalah : %d",diskon);
        }
        else if(jenisp=="Perak"){
            diskon=harga-(0.25*harga);
            printf("Harga untuk pelanggan kartu Perak adalah : %d",diskon);
        }
        else if(jenisp=="Perunggu"){
            diskon=harga-(0.1*harga);
            printf("Harga untuk pelanggan kartu Perunggu adalah : %d",diskon);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Harga untuk bukan pelanggan adalah : %d",harga);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot read into a `std::string` with C functions. Why are you using C++ types but C functions? _Pick one language_ (then tag this question with _just that language_).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You can:  `std:string s(101, ' ' ); scanf("%100s", &s[0]); s.resize(100);`

Comment: @alk: That satisfies only a fairly weak definition of "reading into a `std::string`" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `%c` in `scanf` except `char*` argument and will store one character there. It won't accept `std::string*`.

Using this function may helpful for learning.

```
std::string read_string() {
    char buffer[10000]; // allocate enough memory
    if(scanf("%9999s", buffer) == 1) {
        // successfuly read something
        return buffer;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

To use this, paste this before `int main()` and replace `scanf("%c",&jenisp);` with `jenisp = read_string();`

Comment: @R_Kapp Thank you. Edited.